# How to create a form from scratch using Google Apps Script?

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script, foreach, google-forms

This script adds color selection to the specified form each time it's executed:

```
function initForm() {

  var sheetID = "1C-TqfI989-D-VWFe6Xdvc0LQoqAX2T2C9zUFbkPQSXw";
  var formID = "1E5RS0XI5zaSVrRmeKhjhuZ6fTbe9ORCvsbHQsvuD4-s";

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(sheetID);
  var form = FormApp.openById(formID);

  var colors = ["red", "blue", "green", "black", "orange", "purple"];

  var item = form.addMultipleChoiceItem();
  item.setTitle("colorz");

  colors.forEach(addColor);

  function addColor(color) {
    Logger.log(color);
    item.setChoices([item.createChoice(color)]).showOtherOption(true);
  }
}
```

Instead, how would a **temporary** form be created from scratch?  Rather than using `openById` creating a blank form from scratch?

*(Currently, the colors are hard-coded rather than pulled from a spreadsheet.)*

Comment: Use [`FormApp.create(title)`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form-app#create(String)). If you need further help, please show how you tried to use this method and add a brief description of your search efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Comment: however, this saves the new form every execution.  There's no way to make a temporary form?

Comment: What do you mean by temporary form?

Comment: so that when going to http://forms.google.com/ it's not listed.  A form which doesn't persist.  Looking to create a form on the fly and then remove it.  Non-persistent.

Comment: Why do you need such kind of form in Google Forms?

Comment: For prototyping, if nothing else.  I'll be pulling data from a spreadsheet but haven't settled on the form, and would like to create the form dynamically.  I suppose I can delete all the items in the form, then re-create.

Comment: Using Google Forms you have two options. 1) create and delete a form 2) reuse a form and delete the questions each time. If you need further help, please [edit] the question to clarify what you mean by "temporary" form and the use that you will give to it. P.S. So far the question looks like [Problem X-Y](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/289691).

Comment: Very possibly, as I'm just starting with Google Apps Script.  Incidentally this fellow:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/72739804/4531180  is also looking to generate new forms periodically, although he wants his to persist from what I can see.  As it's the same form, I don't see why he'd want the same exact form, but that's at least my understanding.  Absolutely, still learning very basic things.

Comment: I agree with @Rubén, this seems a XY problem, so far. Could you provide a real case scenario where a temporary Form will be needed? Just an idea, maybe having an existing Form on Drive with your questions and style predefined, then on your script you can copy it and make the necessary modifications...

Comment: Every change results in a new form, and so the old form must be deleted.  That's very real world, to me, to the point where it defeats the purpose of scripting the creation of any specific form, never mind templates.  So I simply disagree there.  Yes, absolutely acknowledge how little I know of javascript, and so I'm coming at things backwards.  I'll point out that a quick search found at least one other person with a similar concern asking on this site -- his concern makes no sense at all to me.

Comment: So to clarify, on the code provided, you reference/open a `Form` by its `Drive Item ID`. Therefore if you always use the same ID, it will always point to the same Form in Drive backend. Can you clarify what you meant by `Every change results in a new form, and so the old form must be deleted.`? I can’t see how a new Form is created every time you run the code provided.

Comment: 'd have to run it again, but there was certainly a surfeit of forms to my recollection.